# to add path from array in the copmponent ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, image, path

I try to add path to image from array.
I would like to create components with different images. I decided to make an array with id and path to image for each id. But It doesnt work. I get Cannot find module '.../build.png

```
`import React from "react";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { Button } from "@mui/material";


export default function EmptyBox() {

    const butArr = [
        {id:1, path: ".../build.png"}
    ]

    
    return(
        
        <Box
        sx={{
            border: "5px solid grey",
            backgroundColor: "#FEF2E4",
            width:"250px",
            height:"auto",
            position: 'absolute', top: "20%", right: "10%",
            borderRadius:"20px"
        }}>
            {butArr.map(item => (
                <Button key={item.id}
                sx={{
                    backgroundImage: `url(${require(item.path)})`,
                    height:"80px",
                    width:"80px",
                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                    backgroundPosition: 'center'
                }}></Button>
                ))}
        </Box>
    )
}`
```

Comment: What bundle tool do you use? Show the config. What's your project structure?